# Simple question about waiting on an AJAX call

Tags: ajax

I need a Javascript function that serves the purpose shown below.  I simply want to wait on the response from the server.

```
console.log('Before getting the city name.');
zip_code = '60601';
city_name = function_that_slowly_gets_city_name_from_server(zip_code);
console.log(city_name);
console.log('After getting the city name.');
```

Output in console:

```
Before getting the city name.
Chicago
After getting the city name.
```

I **do not** want the answer ('Chicago') sent to the console in a callback function. I understand that `async:false` is now taboo with $.ajax(), but I still need for it to work as shown above. I cannot find posts that provide a consistent, straightforward answer.

**FOLLOW UP:**

I've found many answers on StackOverflow that say **synchronous calls are evil**. Yet, is there a way to do it anyway?

Comment: We all have our reasons for doing something "evil" from time to time, but just in case you're trying to accomplish this for the wrong reasons (not saying you are), what's the purpose of trying to force this synchronously? As you may be aware, JS is single-threaded... like really single-threaded. Like if you accomplished this, and made `function_that_slowly_gets_city_name_from_server` synchronous, that would mean your entire app would stop working entirely until you received that response. CSS animations would stop working, typing wouldn't register in inputs, etc... *that* single-threaded

Comment: I understand the issue, but this is an internal application and I need to update the database before allowing further interaction with the client interface. I mean, I literally don't want the user to do anything else for that split second. I can disable the DOM elements, prevent events or otherwise limit the functionality until a callback unwinds that, but, in this instance, that seems like overkill. If the AJAX request doesn't respond in a split second, then there are far worse things happening than locking up a web page. I was just curious. Thanks for your insight. I won't do the evil thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your use-case is a quick method of disabling user-interaction while the AJAX call is occurring to ensure the user can't do anything bad (e.g. start a duplicate request/race condition or navigate to a different part of the app, etc.). So maybe locking the thread ain't such a bad idea then, especially for an internal app that doesn't need a ton of frills?

**But Here's the Problem**:

*The user can continue to queue events even during a locked thread*. That means that any actions the user takes while a synchronous request is occurring (such as submitting a form) will continue to line up in the background, and will then begin firing as soon as the initial request is finished. So the threat of your user double or triple clicking out of impatience (or even just accidentally) -- and as a result causing duplicate calls to the database -- is very real and likely (for reference, I can double click in ~120ms pretty easily).

The same thread is also responsible for things that might surprise you, such as certain browser-level hotkeys or even exiting the tab at all, meaning yes, you could actually significantly delay the user from closing the application, though that's not likely for a low-traffic database. However, it's certainly not impossible, and it's definitely not desirable, even for an application that doesn't need all the frills of a commercial product.

**So What Should I Do as a Quick Solution Instead?**:

Well if you still need a quick solution that can effectively freeze the entirety of your application in one go, then depending on your existing code, this shouldn't be too bad either.

Make the request async, as is the default and standard. But before that request fires, select all elements typically in charge of event handling, disable them with the "disabled" attribute, and then re-enable them in the callback. Something like this:

```js
var userStuff = $("input, button, submit, form");
userStuff.prop("disabled", true);

$.ajax({
    // other ajax request settings ...
    // ...
    // ...
    complete: (data) => {
        userStuff.prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

The elements contained within `userStuff` are just common elements that typically have some event-handling to them. It's up to you to determine if those elements are sufficient for your application, or if your application is so large that such a query could itself have a performance impact. But assuming that checks out, this will prevent the user from interacting with/queueing anything until the request has finished.

**I Don't Care. Give me the Sync**:

Well in that case, why not just use `async: false` as mentioned in your OP? I'm somewhat speculating here, but I believe it's not just `async: false` that's deprecated, but *all means* of synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` (which I believe `$.ajax` still uses under the hood), and I don't think there's any other synchronous alternative to that. So anything you do with synchronous network in mind is going to be evil, but at least in Chrome 89.0, `$.ajax({async: false})` still works for me.

Comment: Impressive answer. And, as you suggested in your last paragraph, an actual solution to my OP probably does not and should not exist, which is why I couldn't find it. I was somewhat surprised by that. You'd think there would be a non-deprecated mechanism to make a synchronous call. On the bright side, the smart folks are preventing us from writing lousy software. Many thanks for your help. --David